# How have I broken this Todo list in ReactJS code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

An earlier draft of code to handle a Todo list, with fewer features, works:

```
        {
        return 0;
        }
      });
    return (
      <div id="Todo">
        <h1>Todo</h1>
        <form onSubmit={that.handleSubmit}>
          <table>
            {table_rows}
            <tfoot>
              <textarea name='todo-textarea' id='todo-textarea'
                onChange={that.onChange}></textarea><br />
              <button>{'Add activity'}</button>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

My present version is getting an InvariantViolation:

> react-with-addons.js:20237 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.1.0.0:0:0.0:1.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

The present code is:

```
var Todo = React.createClass(
{
mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function()
    {
    var result = parse(initial_todo, {
      'next_todo_index': 1,
      'items': [],
      'text': ''
      });
    return result;
    },
  handle_change: function(event)
    {
    var that = this;
    var address = jQuery(event.target).attr('data-index').split('.', 2);
    var identifier = parseInt(address[0], 10);
    for(var candidate = 0; candidate < this.state.next_todo_index;
      candidate += 1)
      {
      if (parseInt(jQuery(this.state.items[candidate]).attr('index'), 10)
        === identifier)
        {
        (this.state.items[candidate][address[1]] =
          !this.state.items[candidate][address[1]]);
        save('Todo', this.state);
        }
      }
    that.render();
    },
  handleSubmit: function(event)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    var new_item = get_todo_item(this);
    new_item.description = this.state.text;
    this.state.items.unshift(new_item);
    document.getElementById('todo-textarea').value = '';
    save('Todo', this.state);
    if (!one_shot)
      {
      one_shot = true;
      }
    // this.forceUpdate();
    // React.render(<Todo />,
      // document.getElementById('Todo'));
    },
  onChange: function(event)
    {
    this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    },
  render: function()
    {
    var that = this;
    var table_rows = [];
    var display_item_details = function(label, item)
      {
      var html_id = item.index + '.' + label;
      return (
        <td className={label} title={label}>
          <input onChange={that.handle_change} data-index={html_id}
          className={label} type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={item[label]} />
        </td>
        );
      };
    var display_item = function(item)
      {
      var rendered_nodes = [];
      if (item['Completed'] || item['Delete'] || item['Invisible'])
        {
        return '';
        }
      else
        {
        for(var index = 0; index < todo_item_names.length;
          index += 1)
          {
          rendered_nodes.push(
            display_item_details(todo_item_names[index], item)
            );
          }
        return (
            <tr>{rendered_nodes}
            <td className="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
              converter.makeHtml(item.description)}} /></tr>
          );
        }
      };
    table_rows.push(that.state.items.map(display_item));
    table_rows.sort(function(a, b)
      {
      if (a.index > b.index)
        {
        return 1;
        }
      else if (b.index > a.index)
        {
        return -1;
        }
      else
        {
        return 0;
        }
      });
    return (
      <div id="Todo">
        <h1>Todo</h1>
        <form onSubmit={that.handleSubmit}>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {table_rows}
            <tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <textarea name='todo-textarea' id='todo-textarea'
                onChange={that.onChange}></textarea><br />
              <button>{'Add activity'}</button>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

How have I broken this?

Comment: "usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables" ?

Comment: @migg Thank you; I put the {table_rows} inside a tbody; that does not change its behavior as far as I can tell. Same InvariantViolation.

Comment: You should start by removing all HTML code one piece at a time until the error goes away.

Comment: You.... you're mixing jQuery with React? :o

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I am mixing *read-only* jQuery with ReactJS. Or trying to. I use it to read data. My understanding is not that you can't get in trouble mixing them, but that it's asking for trouble to use both to mutate the DOM.

Comment: What markup is being returned from `        return (
            <tr>{rendered_nodes}
            <td className="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
              converter.makeHtml(item.description)}} /></tr>
          );`

Answer (score 0):

Do check through your html table structure. Other than the `<tbody>` fix, the usage of `<tfoot>` is also invalid markup.

The `<tfoot>` element can only contain `<tr>` tags inside.

i.e.

`<tfoot>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <textarea name='todo-textarea' id='todo-textarea'
                    onChange={that.onChange}></textarea><br />
                 <button>{'Add activity'}</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tfoot>`